# Minimal generator for a set of sets

Tags: reference-request, np-hardness, set-cover

Is this a known problem?

Given a set of sets $S$ find a set of sets $B$ s.t. each set in $S$ can be obtained through unions of some sets in $B$. The set $S$ is already a solution but the objective is to find the smallest $B$.

For instance $\{\{a,b\}, \{c\}, \{a,b,c\}\}$ can be obtained from $\{\{a,b\}, \{c\}\}$.

Since it's somewhat similar to set-cover, I suspect it's NP-hard.

**Additional remark:** $B$ does not have to be a subset of $S$.

Answer (score 7):

A decision variant, without the minimality condition, asking whether there is a set $B$ of size $n$ is called the set basis problem [SP7] in *Computers and Intractability: A Guide to the Theory of NP-Completeness* by Garey and Johnson. The NP-completeness of it was proved by Stockmeyer.

Comment: Indeed. And the graph-theoretic interpretation of the minimum number is known as bipartite dimension: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_dimension